# Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get, ruby-on-rails-4, httparty

I am trying to request from the [textit.in](http://textit.in) API and display the results of the request to the view using rails 4

I'm using the ['httparty' gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

In my controller I have:

```
  def show
    auth = 'b1363362f8777..etc'
    @sms =  HTTParty.get("https://api.textit.in/api/v1/sms.json", :headers => { "Authorization" => auth} )
  end
```

In the documentation for the site with the API it reads:

"You must authenticate all calls by including an `Authorization` header with your API token. For security reasons all calls must be made using HTTPS.

You Authorization header should look like this:

Authorization: Token YOUR_API_TOKEN_GOES_HERE"

Then in my view I have `<%= @sms %>`

But I get `{"detail"=>"Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

How can I include the Authorization header in my get request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
@sms =  HTTParty.get("https://api.textit.in/api/v1/sms.json", :headers => { "Authorization" => "Token #{auth}" })
```